# Как узнать дату

Tags: perl, время

```
my $time = POSIX::strftime "%H:%M:%S", localtime time;
print "$time\n";
```

так я получаю дату формата час/мин/с
а надо 01/02/2016(день/месяц/год)

Comment: Укажите тег языка

Comment: сделал так my $time = POSIX::strftime  "%e %b %Y", localtime; на выходе 26 Feb 2016, а хотелось бы вместо  Feb (02)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $time = POSIX::strftime "%d:%m:%Y", localtime time;
```

`%d` - `XX` - две цифры - день месяца

`%m` - `XX` - две цифры - номер месяца

`%Y` - `XXXX` - четыре цифры - год

`%y` - `XX` - две цифры - год

также есть формат `%D` - заменяет `%d/%m/%y`

Comment: Отлично то что надо.спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно же проще:

```
$time = sprintf "%02u/%02u%02u", (localtime)[3,4,5];
```

**Обновление**

Был неправ. Поторопился. Нужно:

```
printf "%02u/%02u/%02u\n", (localtime)[3], (localtime)[4]+1, (localtime)[5]+1900;
```